# ERROR 000824 while trying to run IsNull Method outside ArcGIS?

Tags: raster, spatial-analyst, license, pyscripter, error-000824

I am trying to perform `IsNull` function to a raster using PyScripter. This is the code I use:

```py
import arcpy
import arcinfo
InRaster = "C:\\data\InRaster"
IsNullRa = "C:\\data\IsNullRa"
arcpy.gp.IsNull_sa(InRaster, IsNullRa)
```

In ArcGIS Python window, it works OK. However, in a different editor such as PyScripter I get this error:

```
ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed. Failed to execute (IsNull).
```

I have **ArcGIS 10.1** and do have **spatial analyst**. I tried installing  Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64) from [here](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39846) but it did not work. Do you know how I can run IsNull outside of ArcGIS? Thanks.

Comment: In addition to an answer to your specific question (see below), I think that the preferred syntax for the [IsNull](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000m8000000.htm) tool is `IsNullRa = arcpy.IsNull(InRaster)`

Comment: Great! I had used ArcGIS Geo processing model builder to come up with the weird syntax I used! Your syntax is definitely easier.

Comment: That would actually be IsNullRa = arcpy.**sa**.IsNull(InRaster)

Comment: Yes, good catch. Or include `from arcpy.sa import *` in the initial setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [check out the extension outside of ArcGIS](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00p600000016000000), add this line at the beginning of the script, after the `import` statements.

```
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
```

Comment: It totally works! I had thought that `arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")` is used just for checking whether you have "Spatial" extension. Well, it seems that it actually activates the extension for uses outside of ArcGIS.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem :)

Comment: If you're outside of ArcMap yes you do need to activate extensions but also you should be deactivating the extensions as well when you're finished with them or you could end up holding onto an extension license with no process. To do this use arcpy.CheckInExtenstion.